# contiki-z1-main.c : "undefined reference to 'autostart_processes'"

Tags: c, contiki

When I try to compile a .c file with Cooja, Contiki, there are these errors:

```
 contiki-z1-main.c(.init9+0x200): undefined reference to `autostart_processes`
 contiki-z1-main.c(.init9+0x224): undefined reference to `autostart_processes`
```

Does anyone know the issue?

Comment: I think you should give us more details about your problem: (share your source code).

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.
I would highly appreciate it if you shared with us any possible solutions that you might had.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the `AUTOSTART_PROCESSES()`, so Contiki does not know where to start executing your application.

For eg Blink,

```
PROCESS(blink_process, "Blink example");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&blink_process);
```

Answer (score 0):

Becasuse of that the "AUTOSTART_PROCESSES" is defined not correctly.

In file "autostart.h",you could find the code there:

```
#if AUTOSTART_ENABLE
#define AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(...)                    \
struct process * const autostart_processes[] = {__VA_ARGS__, NULL}
#else /* AUTOSTART_ENABLE */
#define AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(...)                    \
extern int _dummy
```

So if you dont't define "AUTOSTART_ENABLE" as 1, the autostart function won't work, and your process will not start.