# Error when linking a contiki object file with a RUST library

Tags: c, contiki

I have an object file of an app based on Contiki which I am trying to link with a static library generated out of a RUST source file. When I try linking them as following:

`gcc -o out myObj.o contiki-native.a libsimple.a -Wl,--gc-sections -lpthread`

I get the following error:

`/./native/./contiki-main.c:246: undefined reference to 'autostart_processes'`

Answer (score 0):

I feel this might be your problem -

You need to define `AUTOSTART_PROCESSES()`

the following answer might help you -

[contiki-z1-main.c : "undefined reference to 'autostart_processes'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686384/contiki-z1-main-c-undefined-reference-to-autostart-processes)